# Combine reducers

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux

How do I combine the two reducers?

PeopleReducer.js

```js
const initialState = {
    people: [],
    detailView: false,
    personSelected: null,
    first_name: '',
    last_name: '',
    phone: '',
    email: '',
    country: '',
    address: '',
    company: '',
    project: '',
    notes: '',
    toUpdate: false,
};

export default (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'INITIAL_FETCH':
            return {
                ...state,
                people: action.payload,
            }

        case 'SELECTED_PERSON':
            return {
                ...state,
                detailView: true,
                personSelected: action.payload
            }
            
        case 'NONE_SELECTED':
            return {
                ...state,
                detailView: false,
                personSelected: null,
            }
            
        case 'FORM_UPDATE':
            return {
                ...state,
                [action.payload.prop]: action.payload.value
            };
        
        case 'NEW_CONTACT':
            return {
                ...state,
                first_name: '',
                last_name: '',
                phone: '',
                email: '',
                country: '',
                address: '',
                company: '',
                project: '',
                notes: '',
            }
        
        case 'ADD_PERSON':
            return {
                ...state,
                ...action.newPerson
            };
        
        case 'UPDATE_CONTACT':
            return {
                ...state,
                toUpdate: true,
                first_name: action.payload.first_name,
                last_name: action.payload.last_name,
                phone: action.payload.phone,
                email: action.payload.email,
                country: action.payload.country,
                address: action.payload.address,
                company: action.payload.company,
                project: action.payload.project,
                notes: action.payload.notes,
                uid: action.payload.uid,
            }
        
        case 'SAVE_CONTACT':
            return {
                ...state,
                toUpdate: false,
                detailView: false,
                first_name: '',
                last_name: '',
                phone: '',
                email: '',
                country: '',
                address: '',
                company: '',
                project: '',
                notes: '',
                uid: '',
            };
        
        case 'DELETE_CONTACT':
            return {
                ...state,
                detailView: false,
                personSelected: null,
            }

        default:

            return state;
    }
}
```

CompanyReducer.js

```js
const initialState = {
    company: [],
    detailViewCompany: false,
    companySelected: null,
    contractNumber: '',
    nameCompany: '',
    startDate: '',
    endDate: '',
    duration: '',
    contractType: '',
    parties: '',
    description: '',
    contractValue: '',
    toUpdateCompany: false,
};

export default (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'INITIAL_FETCH_COMPANY':
            return {
                ...state,
                company: action.payload,
            }

        case 'SELECTED_COMPANY':
            return {
                ...state,
                detailViewCompany: true,
                companySelected: action.payload
            }
            
        case 'NONE_SELECTED_COMPANY':
            return {
                ...state,
                detailViewCompany: false,
                companySelected: null,
            }
            
        case 'FORM_UPDATE_COMPANY':
            return {
                ...state,
                [action.payload.prop]: action.payload.value
            };
        
        case 'NEW_COMPANY':
            return {
                ...state,
                contractNumber: '',
                nameCompany: '',
                startDate: '',
                endDate: '',
                duration: '',
                contractType: '',
                parties: '',
                description: '',
                contractValue: '',
            }
        
        case 'ADD_COMPANY':
            return {
                ...state,
                ...action.newCompany
            };
        
        case 'UPDATE_COMPANY':
            return {
                ...state,
                toUpdateCompany: true,
                contractNumber: action.payload.contractNumber,
                nameCompany: action.payload.nameCompany,
                startDate: action.payload.startDate,
                endDate: action.payload.endDate,
                duration: action.payload.duration,
                contractType: action.payload.contractType,
                parties: action.payload.parties,
                description: action.payload.description,
                contractValue: action.payload.contractValue,
                uid: action.payload.uid,
            }
        
        case 'SAVE_COMPANY':
            return {
                ...state,
                toUpdateCompany: false,
                detailViewCompany: false,
                contractNumber: '',
                nameCompany: '',
                startDate: '',
                endDate: '',
                duration: '',
                contractType: '',
                parties: '',
                description: '',
                contractValue: '',
                uid: '',
            };
        
        case 'DELETE_COMPANY':
            return {
                ...state,
                detailViewCompany: false,
                companySelected: null,
            }

        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

App.tsx

```
declare const window: any;
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, ImageBackground } from 'react-native';
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';
import 'firebase/compat/auth';
import 'firebase/compat/database';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux'
import Login from './Login';
import Loader from './Loader';
import Navigation from './Navigation';
import reducers from '../reducers/PeopleReducer';
import Thunk from 'redux-thunk';

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  background: {
    flex: 1,
    resizeMode: 'cover',
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
  },
  navigationContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
  },
});

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "XYZ",
  authDomain: "xyz-12345.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://xyz-12345-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app",
  projectId: "xyz-12345",
  storageBucket: "xyz-12345.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "123456789",
  appId: "1:1234:web:56789"
};

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

const store = createStore(reducers, window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__(), applyMiddleware(Thunk));

export default class App extends Component {
  state = { loggedIn: null};

  componentDidMount() {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user: any) => {
        if (user) {
          this.setState({ loggedIn: true });
        } else {
          this.setState({ loggedIn: false});
        }
      });
  }

  renderInitialView() {
    if (this.state.loggedIn === null) {
      return <Loader size="large" />;
    } else {
      switch(this.state.loggedIn){
        case true:
          return (
            <View style={styles.navigationContainer}>
              <Navigation />
            </View>
          );
        case false:
          return <Login />;
        default:
          return <Loader size="large" />;
      }
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <ImageBackground source={require('../components/images/img2.jpg')} style={styles.background}>
          <View style={styles.container}>
            {this.renderInitialView()}
          </View>
        </ImageBackground>
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

The two imported individually in App.tsx work perfectly. I tried to combine the two reducers with redux, but neither works when combined. I want you to tell me how I could make the two work together and how to implement them in App.tsx.

Answer (score 0):

Using redux's `combineReducers` function:

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import peopleReducer from '../reducers/PeopleReducer';
import companyReducer from '../reducers/CompanyReducer';

const reducers = {
  people: peopleReducer,
  companies: companyReducer
}

const reducer = combineReducers(reducers);

const store = createStore(reducers, window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__(), applyMiddleware(Thunk));
```

Comment: I've tried this one, it doesn't work

Comment: @GrosuAlexandra Using `combineReducers` to *combine your reducers* is correct. What ***specifically*** isn't  working for you? Please edit your post to more clearly explain what *specific* issue you are trying to resolve is.

Comment: I identified the problem, was the "company" of PersonReducer , I changed in personCompany and it worked